# Wix Burn (Standard Bootstrapper Application)

Tags: wix

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_customize.html shows how to manipulate the predefined layouts.  Is it possible to create additional layouts and NOT have to recompile the application?  For example – we can imagine having screen1 display options for MSI1 and screen2 display options for MSI2.  If MSI3 is introduced later which has its own set of options, would we have to define a new layout and then rebuild the entire bootstrapper app?

Or is there a way to “plug in” the new layout at the end without rebuilding?    Wixstdba expects themes to be embedded into the Bundle so updating a theme requires rebuilding the bundle when using wixstdba.

I tried few instructions listed on forums, they did not work as expected. Any information on this would be greatly  appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, as you said WixStdBA currently expects themes to be embedded in the bundle.  But if you add an MSI to the bundle, you're going to have to recompile it anyway so that the bundle knows about the new MSI.